# How to apply conditional formatting to multiple columns based on each columns own values

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have a data which looks like this:
[image: dataExample]

I want to use the Red-White-Green color scale formatting for each column.
I have almost 250 columns but when I select multiple columns, they get colorized based on all the values I have selected. I only want to colorize each column based on the values of that column.

Here is a example showing what is happening when I select multiple columns:

[image: MultipleColumnSelecting]

Here is how I want to do it:

[image: TheWayIwantedToDo]

How can I apply the rule for all columns based on each column's own values?

Comment: You need a separate rule for each column. Can be applied using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben)'s suggestion and came up with the following code:

```vb
Sub test()
For Each Column In Range("B2:IA36").Columns
  Dim MyRange As Range
  Column.Select
  Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
  Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
  Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 8109667 'Color of lowest. Can be replaced with RGB(r, g, b).
    End With
    
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'Color of middle value
    End With
    
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 7039480 'Color of highest. Can be replaced with RGB(r, g, b)
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

I got the most of the code from [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/conditional-formatting/). I only added the for loop part to iterate through columns. To apply it into your own data, you only need to change the range(First comes upper-left cell then comes lower-right cell) in line 2.